# Cordova Facebook plugin (ionic framework)

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using $cordovaFacebook plugin (http://ngcordova.com/docs/#Facebook) and my question is: How to keep FB Login on session?
Curiously, the web version is working but iOS version not. 
My code:

(controllers.js)

```
    angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$cordovaFacebook', '$state', function($scope, $cordovaFacebook, $state) {   
    $scope.FacebookLoginBtn = function() {
        $cordovaFacebook.login(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends", "user_relationship_details", "user_photos"])
        .then(function(success) {  
            $state.go('perfil');
        }, function (error) {
          // error
          console.log(error);
        });
    };
}])

.controller('PerfilCtrl', ['$scope', '$cordovaFacebook', function ($scope, $cordovaFacebook) {
    $cordovaFacebook.api("me/picture?redirect=false&type=large", ["public_profile"])
    .then(function (success) {
        $scope.foto = success.data;
        // console.log(success.data);
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

    $cordovaFacebook.api("me", ["public_profile"])
    .then(function(success) {
        $scope.me = success;
        // console.log(success);
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}])
```

Thanks!
Ionic forum link: http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cordova-facebook-plugin/13569/1

Comment: Use html5 session storage

Comment: Hi @shammon ... I really thought on this alternative but I found another option: http://benjamin.my/how-to-set-up-facebook-connect-plugin-and-parse-com-in-ionic-phonegap/